# Indy IdHttp Digest Authentication - 401

Tags: indy, digest-authentication, idhttp

When you try to take a picture from a camera, the authentication function does not work. I read all the other posts on the subject, but without success with this device.

Indy 10.6.2.0

```
Uses ..., IdAuthentication, IdAuthenticationDigest;

...

  addr   := 'cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?1';
  myADR :=  'http://87.126.245.25:8181/' + addr;

  rStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try

    H1 := TIdHttp.Create();

    {$IFDEF DEBUG}
    idLogFile := TIdLogFile.Create( H1 );
    with idLogFile do begin
      Filename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter( ExtractFileDir( Application.ExeName ) ) + 'indy_log.txt';
      Active := true;
    end;
    {$ENDIF}

    with H1 do begin

      Response.KeepAlive          := true;
      ReadTimeout                 := selCAM.Timeout;
      Request.BasicAuthentication := false;
      Request.Username            := selCAM.User;
      Request.Password            := selCAM.Pass;
      Request.ContentType         := 'image/jpeg';
      Request.UserAgent           := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Chrome/97.0.4692.71';
      Request.ContentVersion      := '1.0';
      Request.IPVersion           := Id_IPv4;
      Request.Host                := 'http://' + addr;

      HTTPOptions := [hoInProcessAuth, hoForceEncodeParams];
    
      OnSelectAuthorization := IdHTTP_SelectAuthorization;
      OnHeadersAvailable    := IdHTTP_HeadersAvailable;
      OnAuthorization       := IdHTTP_Authorization;

      {$IFDEF DEBUG}  Intercept := idLogFile; {$ENDIF}
    end;

    try
    
      H1.Get( myADR, rStream); except

      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin SB1.Panels[0].Text := E.Message; er := true; end;
      on E: EIdException             do begin SB1.Panels[0].Text := E.Message; er := true; end;
      on E: Exception                do begin SB1.Panels[0].Text := E.Message; er := true; end;

    end;

  finally
    H1.Free;
    FreeAndNil(rStream);
  end;
```

It works correctly through a browser

Attach wireshark from Browser, from Indy and Indy Log:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AubiEh1vqvRLkr01GzXCf_T0yLgmfQ?e=69dqaD

Comment: I don't have opportunity to look at your logs right now, but just on a side note, I see some mistakes in your code. `Response.KeepAlive := true;` should be `Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';` and `Request.ContentType` should be omitted completely since you are not sending data to the server, and `Request.Host` should be omitted since `TIdHTTP` will manage it internally for you. That being said, in the `OnSelectAuthorization` event handler, do you see `TIdHTTP` attempting to use `TIdDigestAuthentication`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the notes. The code has been corrected, but with these I guess it is clear to us that we are still not successful. In procedure IdHTTP_SelectAuthorization we put  `Memo1.Lines.Add( 'IdHTTP_AuthenticationClass: ' + AuthenticationClass.ClassName );
  Memo1.Lines.Add( 'IdHTTP_SelectAuthorization: ' + AuthInfo.Text );` and result is `IdHTTP_AuthenticationClass: TIdDigestAuthentication
IdHTTP_SelectAuthorization: Digest realm="Login to E3C3B471E6FB7A93", qop="auth", nonce="a8412ca3-b0dc-4bec-a605-8f42f0da2535", opaque=""`

Comment: In your Indy logs, I see no attempt from `TIdHTTP` to send a Digest authentication to the server, which would imply that `TIdDigestAuthentication` is not producing any data for `TIdHTTP` to use in an `Authorization` request header.  You can see that header is present in the Edge log. Your code is assigning `selCAM.User` to `TIdHTTP.Request.Username`, but is that actually a non-empty string? Also, you are assigning a `TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization` event handler, is that event being fired at all? In this situation, it should be fired when the `UserName` is unknown, or the server rejects the auth.

Comment: This is exactly the problem! For some reason no attempt from TIdHTTP to send a Digest authentication to the server. 1. selCAM is a variable that certainly has a value. 2. TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization event NOT fire when selCAM has data, and fired when is empty (I did tests)! This camera address is absolutely real and responds from all over the world 24/7, it can be tested to see if TidHTTP tries to send Digest Authentication. <hr/> url: http://87.126.245.25:8181/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?1

Comment: I don't have a working compiler installed right now, so I have no means of testing this myself. I can only go off of Indy's source code, and analyzing that is telling me that a Digest `Authentication` header *should* be getting sent, but in your case it is clearly not. So, you will just have to debug into Indy's code for yourself to figure out why `TIdDigestAuthentication` is not working correctly. If you find the cause, I can then checkin a fix. In the meantime, I have opened a ticket in Indy's issue tracker: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/397

Comment: I see that in order to make the request we need TIdDigestAuthentication.Authentication - FCurrentStep = 1 (Build request). In TIdDigestAuthentication.DoNext - if Length(Username) > 0 then FCurrentStep := 1;  But after that he never enters the procedure (Authentication) to make an correct header.

Comment: `TIdDigestAuthentication.Authentication` is used in `TIdRequestHeaderInfo.SetHeaders()`, which is called while the HTTP request is being built for transmission. Handling of the 401 response calls `TIdCustomHTTP.DoOnAuthorization()`, which calls `TIdDigestAuthentication.Next()`, and if it returns `wnDoRequest` then the request is retried, giving `TIdDigestAuthentication.Authentication` a chance to build the `Authorization` header.

Comment: I can't find why he doesn't create the right request. I see where he has to do it, but nowhere is the variable FCurrentStep incremented to 1 to Build request !!!

Comment: For this project I move to another tool. I will follow the ticket to find out what the problem is.