# Delphi 11.3 Windows app with Indy and digest authentication fails intermittently

Tags: authentication, delphi, hash, indy

I'm currently writing code for interfacing with a biometric device which requires digest auth in some requests. I wrote a simple app for testing, which works well in my PC and others, but there are a couple ones in which said app works intermittently; sometimes it works, sometimes I receive a 401 code (unauthorized). My app is as follows:

- Windows VCL application, target: win32
- Drop a TidHTTP, enable hoInProcessAuth in property HTTPOptions, also drop a button and a memo

Code goes like follows:

```
{ IdAuthenticationDigest is included in Uses };  

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdHttp1.OnAuthorization:=IdHTTPAuthorization;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTPAuthorization(Sender: TObject;
  Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Authentication.Username := 'xxxxxx';    { I'm using the same user/password }
  Authentication.Password := 'xxxxxx';
  Handled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

Var
  fs: TStringStream;

begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear();

  fs:=TStringStream.Create();

  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Username:='xxxxxx';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Password:='xxxxxx';

  IdHTTP1.Get('http://192.168.0.147/ISAPI/System/capabilities', fs);

  fs.Position:=0;

  { A memo to show response }
  Memo1.Lines.Clear();
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(fs, TEncoding.UTF8);

  fs.Free();
end;
```

I'm using Delphi 11.3, running on Windows 10 Pro, and Indy 10.6.2.0. No firewalls or antivirus are running at the time of tests. Like I said before, this works on my PC 100%, but on other PC's (same network) doesn't; it works about 80% of tries, but suddenly I receive a 401 status. Can't find why. If anyone has an idea, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance.

**Things I tried**

- Tried running in Postman, no errors, always get a 200 status.
- Tried running the compiled app in several PC's.

**What I expected**

To send requests and receive a 200 status. Works in most PC's though, but on some it shows a 401 status, then works again.

Comment: Likely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710504/ (see https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/397 and maybe https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/182). Did you try sniffing the HTTP requests to see if `TIdHTTP` is sending/omitting the digest `Authorization` header in the cases that fail?

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, I haven't, will investigate into that. I'll come back with my findings.

Comment: The easiest way to sniff the HTTP messages is to attach one of the `TIdLog...` components, such as `TIdLogFile`, to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property.

Comment: @RemyLebeau here's a small log after three button presses: first two returned 401, then 200:

https://pastebin.com/fUniHUBa

PS: removed IP's and username just to be on the safe side.

Comment: It would have been nice if you had separated the logs for each button press, but whatever. All of the GET requests except for the last one are missing an `Authorization` header. So this would seem to be another case of the bug mentioned in the links I posted earlier. I need to look into that...

Comment: ... In the meantime, you can try implementing Digest manually (see [RFC 7616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7616)) by handling the 401, checking `TIdHTTP.Response.Headers` for the `WWE-Authentication` response header, and then use `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders` to retry the request with a valid `Authorization` header.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry for the lack of separation in the log, honestly didn't think of that. Thank you for your time and advice.